# Restarting failed sub-jobs

Tags: autosys

I have set of 50 sub jobs under a single box in **Autosys**. Few of them failed. I want to restart only failed sub jobs after all jobs have triggered at least once.

How can I use `n_retrys` is this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

n_retrys: is only when the job fails, it will use when it should retry failed job based on config in seconds + seconds between each other restart.